# python, How can I put and if to a function that raise an error?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, cycle

Hi all I am checking for cycle in the graph

```
import networkx as nx
X2 = {"1": ["4"], "2": ["3"], "3": ["2", "4"], "4": ["1", "3"]}
L2 = []
for k,v in X2.items():
    for i in range(len(v)):
        L2.append((k,v[i]))
print(L2)
G = nx.DiGraph(L2)
G = G.to_undirected()

print(type(G))
print(nx.find_cycle(G))
```

In this case correctly there aren't cycle so the nx function raise:

```
raise nx.exception.NetworkXNoCycle('No cycle found.')
networkx.exception.NetworkXNoCycle: No cycle found.
```

How can I put and If condition to print something if the function raise me the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for here is **error handling**. It works like an `if` for errors like you want.

You achieve this with a `try/except` block. More details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

```
import networkx as nx
X2 = {"1": ["4"], "2": ["3"], "3": ["2", "4"], "4": ["1", "3"]}
L2 = []
for k,v in X2.items():
    for i in range(len(v)):
        L2.append((k,v[i]))
print(L2)
try:
    G = nx.DiGraph(L2)
    G = G.to_undirected()
    print(type(G))
    print(nx.find_cycle(G))
except:
    print("Error message")
```

Comment: and if I want to put a condition instead then print("Error message")

Comment: You can have anything you need in the `except` part, what kind of condition would you need ?

Comment: @Supposing that instead having only 1 graph X2 I have 10 graph I would like to divide the one with cycle and the one without cycle.

Comment: I don't think I can answer your question since I've never worked with `networkx`. I'm sure that you can implement this in your `except` block if that is how you will handle your exception.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "try" and "except" keywords, read up exception handling in python.

Basically you need to:

```
try:
   your_function_call(arguments)
except nx.exception.NetworkXNoCycle as e:
   print("Found the no cycle exception)
```